# Rails stopped logging anything development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was messing around with a contact form gem and it seems completely unexpectedly my log is no longer...well logging. It used to log every get request, now it logs nothing.

Here is the gem
https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us‎

Bit of a vicious circle because without a log its hard to diagnose the problem, the problem being the log not working itself.

Any suggestions as to how I could find the root of the problem?

Comment: did you try removing the gem to see if the log came back?

Comment: I did, no avail unfortunately

Comment: Well, there's not much info to go on...

Comment: haha exactly my problem :/ I don't really know what else I can provide...I guess this is the day I learn to use version control

Comment: Hm so I deleted the log file, and added `config.log_level = :debug` to my dev env config, after doing this the dev log was downloaded, but is empty..

Comment: Server restart fixed it :/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the gem. deleting the log, `config.log_level = :debug` to my dev env config and subsequently restarting the server. Although I'm not if the previous steps we're necessary, the problem could have perhaps been solved by restarting nginx.